# Display Excel cell that contains text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Lets say i have exel with columns:

```
John 1234,Jerry 8329, Michael 2312
Jerry 5543,John 6423, Michael 4324
Michael 1122,Jerry 5345, John 3354
```

I'm looking for a Excell formula that woud search through  those 3 columns for cell containing word "John" and display cells full content.

End result shoud look like :

```
John 1234,Jerry 8329, Michael 2312 = John 1234
Jerry 5543,John 6423, Michael 4324 = John 6423
Michael 1122,Jerry 5345, John 3354 = John 3354
```

So far I only managed to find formula that says in what column searched word is found:

```
=MATCH("*John*";A1:C1;0)
```

Perhaps it will help somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, good start,

Try this in **D1** and drag it down

`=INDEX(A1:C1,MATCH("*John*",A1:C1,0))`